# push data using REST API as source data to Azure Data factory pipeline

Tags: api, rest, azure-data-factory

azure experts out there,

I have a specific requirement to be able to push data to the Azure Data Factory pipeline as the source. I understand the common pattern is to let ADF Pipeline pull data from the source REST API on schedule and push data to Sink like Blob storage

REST API(Source) <---- ADF ----> Blob (Sink) - Common Pattern where ADF Actively pulls from the source and pushes to sink (Data flow is Triggered based on schedule)

REST API(Source) ----> ADF ----> Blob (Sink) - Required flow where Client API Push data to ADF and ADF write data to sink (Data flow is triggered based on client API instantly)

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: How are you pushing the data to Azure data factory from your Rest source?

Comment: we've our existing API that can POST data as body and want to be able to configure that existing API to be able to trigger data pipeline instead of scheduling data pipeline to poll frequently

Answer (score 1):

There is a REST API for the Data Factory, here is the link to the documentation for the endpoint that creates a Pipeline run

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run?tabs=HTTP

There are Data Factory triggers for Storage Events or Event Grid if you prefer to have your REST API use those.